# Datasource Configuration for JUnit using Maven

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, junit4

We’ve configured multiple Spring Boot profiles in our application and data source changes according to the profile activated.

We’ve separate data source for Junit Tests. Now, we want to use this data source for JUnit Tests irrespective of the profile activated.

We were able to achieve this using `@TestPropertySource` in every test class but we need this configuration in one place in `pom.xml`. I’m aware of maven-surefire-plugin which is used to execute Junit Tests but not sure how we can configure particular data source there.

Is there any way to achieve this? 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just specify the active profile or annotate a base class with `@ActiveProfile` .

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this is to create profile-dependable configuratons as wrappers over normal configurations, like this:

Profile 1:

```
@Profile("ds1")
@Import(Ds1Configuration.class)
public class Ds1ProfileConfiguration {}
```

Profile 2:

```
@Profile("ds2")
@Import(Ds2Configuration.class)
public class Ds2ProfileConfiguration {}
```

where the imported configurations contain actual bean definitions:

```
public class Ds1Configuration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){...}
}
```

and

```
public class Ds2Configuration {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){...}
}
```

This will separate your profiles and configurations, so you will be able to use these in your tests:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Ds2Configuration.class)
```